# incorrect sql query generated by spring data jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller

Given the repository below

```
@Repository
public interface DashboardRepository
       extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Dashboard, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT " +
           "    d " +
           "FROM " + 
           "    Dashboard d " + 
           "WHERE " + 
           "    d.branchUserId= :userId " +
           "OR  d.restUserId = :userId " + 
           "ORDER BY " +
           "    d.orderId DESC")
    Page<Dashboard> findByBranchUserIdOrRestUserId(@Param("userId") Long userId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

When I make a call to `findByBranchUserIdOrRestUserId` I see the following query generated:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(dashboard0_.ORDER_ID) AS col_0_0_
FROM
    DAILY_ORDERS dashboard0_
WHERE
    dashboard0_.BRANCH_USER_ID=?
OR dashboard0_.REST_USER_ID=?
```

Any clues what might be the issue?

**UPDATE**: The `Dashboard` entity is mapped to a database view. When I execute `SELECT * FROM [view name]` directly on the database I get rows back. However, when I execute `dashboardRepository.count()`, I get zero.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume this has to do with Spring's inferred "countQuery"

In the docs is talks about Pagination and custom @Queries

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
    nativeQuery = true)
  Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: when I check for dashboardRepository.count() I get 0. My entity is mapped to database view. when I do select * from my_view (directly on db) I see rows there, not sure why I am seeing 0 records returned and count is 0